# Matrix multiplication and dot-product

Tags: lisp, scheme, matrix, sicp

> Exercise 2.37.  Suppose we represent
>   vectors v = (vi) as sequences of
>   numbers, and matrices m = (mij) as
>   sequences of vectors (the rows of the
>   matrix). For example, the matrix
>   [image: matrix m]
>
> is represented as the sequence ((1 2 3
>   4) (4 5 6 6) (6 7 8 9)). With this
>   representation, we can use sequence
>   operations to concisely express the
>   basic matrix and vector operations.
>   These operations (which are described
>   in any book on matrix algebra) are the
>   following:

[image: matrix multiplication equations]

> We can define the dot product as17
>
> ```
> (define (dot-product v w)
> (accumulate + 0 (map * v w)))
> ```
>
> Fill in the missing expressions in the
>   following procedures for computing the
>   other matrix operations. (The
>   procedure accumulate-n is defined in
>   exercise 2.36.)
>
> ```
> (define (matrix-*-vector m v)
>   (map <??> m))
> (define (transpose mat)
>   (accumulate-n <??> <??> mat))
> (define (matrix-*-matrix m n)
>   (let ((cols (transpose n)))
>     (map <??> m)))
> ```

I wrote the following solutions:

```
(define (accumulate op initial items)
  (if (null? items)
      initial
      (op (car items) (accumulate op initial (cdr items)))))

(define (accumulate-n op init seqs)
  (if (null? (car seqs))
      null
      (cons (accumulate op init (map (lambda (x) (car x)) seqs))
            (accumulate-n op init (map (lambda (x) (cdr x)) seqs)))))

(define (dot-product v w)
  (accumulate + 0 (map * v w)))

(define (matrix-*-vector m v)
  (accumulate-n +
                0
                (map (lambda (row) 
                       (map (lambda (i j) (* i j)) row v)) m)))

(define (transpose mat)
  (accumulate-n (lambda (x y) (cons x y)) null mat))

(define (matrix-*-matrix m n) 
  (let ((cols (transpose n)))
    (map (lambda (m-row) 
           (accumulate-n +
                         0
                         (map (lambda (col) 
                                (map * m-row col))
                              cols))) m)))


(define m1 (list (list 1 2 3 4) (list 4 5 6 6) (list 6 7 8 9)))
(define m2 (list (list 10 20 30) (list 40 50 60) (list 70 80 90) (list 100 110 120)))

(define v1 (list 10 20 30 40))
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `transpose` is correct, although it can be written succinctly as:

```
(define (transpose mat)
  (accumulate-n cons null mat))
```

The remaining two definitions may be written more succinctly by using functions defined earlier.  Notice that multiplying a matrix to a vector is conceptually the same as obtaining the dot-product of the vector and each row of the matrix.  Thus, one may define `matrix-*-vector` as:

```
(define (matrix-*-vector m v)
  (map (lambda (row) (dot-product v row)) m))
```

The above definition satisfies the requirement of the exercise.

Similarly, matrix multiplication of A to B is the same as transposing B and performing a matrix-vector multiplication with each row of A.  Thus, one may define `matrix-*-matrix` as:

```
(define (matrix-*-matrix m n)
  (let
      ((cols (transpose n)))
    (map (lambda (row) (matrix-*-vector cols row)) m)))
```

If you wish to go farther than the exercise requires, you may consider using function currying.  Currying allows one to apply a function to arguments incrementally.  If your implementation of Scheme provides the `curry` function, you may write:

```
(define (matrix-*-vector m v)
  (map (curry dot-product v) m))

(define (matrix-*-matrix m n)
  (map (curry matrix-*-vector (transpose n)) m))
```